# Is there a way to add '-lpthread' to default linker flag without change the makefile

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

HI,

I am getting the following linker error on linux:
My guess is it is missing '-lpthread' in the linker thread.  My question is if there is a way for me to set my environment on linux such that it will add '-lpthread' when it links?

/usr/bin/ld: out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libutils_intermediates/libutils.a(Threads.o): in function androidCreateRawThreadEtc:frameworks/base/libs/utils/Threads.cpp:145: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_create'

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell us more about how exactly you are compiling with gcc.

For example, if you are using a Makefile, the you can add `-lpthread` to the `CFLAGS` environment variable.

**Edit:** If you compile and link in two steps, then you should use the `LDFLAGS` environment variable for controlling the linker flags.

Comment: Isn't CFLAGS normaly for compiling? I.e. if you have compiling and linking in two steps, you normaly use LDFLAGS for the linking.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that he does compile and link in one step (because of the gcc tag). Updated my answer.